# Execute jQuery script after its being loaded in via jQuery .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

In page Index.html there is a selectbox called `#choose_content_to_load` and a div called `#get_loaded_content`

```
<select id="choose_content_to_load">
<option>Some content from page content.html and div #content</option>
</select

<div id="get_loaded_content">
```

As seen in the selectbox option there is a page called `content.html` that contains a div called `#content`. In the current situation the div `#content` get loaded into `#get_loaded_content` when click on the option by using this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#choose_content_to_load").change(function(){ 
    var selectedOption = $('#choose_content_to_load :selected').val(); 
    $containerDiv = $('#get_loaded_content'); 
    $containerDiv.html("");
       switch (selectedOption)
       {
        case "Some content from page content.html and div #content":$containerDiv.load( "content.html #content" , function(){$(document).trigger("reload_javascript");});break;
       }
    return true;
    }); 
});
```

As you see the script also trigger a "reload" of all the scripts "reload_javascript". This is becuse the div `#content` have some more design elements that needs to be executed at the load in. These scripts looks like this:

```
$(document).on("ready reload_javascript" ,function() {
script
});
```

This works fine and all the loaded elements initializes and works, this becuse `Index.html` and `content.html` share the same design scripts (same .js file) so the scripts just need to "run again" to work. Now to the problem, the div `#content` need to have a larger script that only execute when the div is being loaded into `#get_loaded_content` in `Index.html`. Its not good to have the script in the .js file that both `index.html` and `content.html` share becuse its alot of code.

So the new script need to be put direct into the `#content` html using  tags and execute when this div is being loaded in.

First I thought the new script will run just by adding the `reload_javascript` but then I realised that dident execute the script just initialize it (I think). I hope somebody can help me with this and please have in mind that I try to learn jQuery (beginner at coding).

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you are loading `<script>` tags into content and wish for it to execute? If so call this function i made a while back after insertion.

```
/**
*This function is supposed to execute script after script insertions
*/
function execute(){
    $('#content script').each(function() {
        var _script = document.createElement('script');
        _script.type = 'text/javascript';
        _script.setAttribute('async', 'true');
    /**
    *IEFIX (IE does not support .innerHTML on createElement)
    **/
        if(!_script.innerHTML){
        _script.text=$(this).html().replace('\\\\',"\\");
        }else{
        _script.innerHTML  = $(this).html().replace('\\\\',"\\");
        }
        document.body.appendChild(_script); 
    });
}
```

Comment: The div #content from page content.html get loaded into #get_loaded_content in Index.html. The div #content contains a script direct in the HTML code <script>something</script> that I want to execute when the div gets loaded in. I think I need to modify the loadin script (to the selectbox) but I really dont know how. At the moment it just initializes all the "reload_javascript" scripts. Can your script be modifyed to the loadin script in the first post?

Comment: Actually i just copy-pasted it from my script file, your content-div may have another name

The basic idea here is that if content script is loaded into a DIV or similar the script will be executed whenever this function is called. You may put execute() just before your "return true;" if the div with the ID "Content" has script-blocks they will be executed.